# how to store JSON in POSTGRES using SpringBoot + JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a payload that am trying to save into a database, whenever I post the payload, it returns the mapped JSON objects as null instead of the values in the payload passed.

here is the JSON payload

```
{
    "authStatus": {
        "authStatusCode": 131,
        "authStatusDescription": "API call doesn't need authentication"
    },
    "results": {
        "beepTransactionID": 10764659,
        "payerTransactionID": "5f51eed7347a7",
        "statusCode": "188",
        "statusDescription": "Response was received"
    }
}
```

after posting it to postman

```
{
    "id": 14,
    "authStatusCode": null,
    "authStatusDescription": null,
    "beepTransactionID": null,
    "payerTransactionID": null,
    "statusCode": null,
    "statusDescription": null
}
```

my controller for posting

```
     @PostMapping("/payload")
        public Payload createPayload(@Valid @RequestBody Payload payload) {
            return payloadRepository.save(payload);
        }
```

my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payload", schema = "public")
    public class Payload {
        private long id;
        Integer authStatusCode;
        String authStatusDescription;
        Integer beepTransactionID;
        String payerTransactionID;
        String statusCode;
        String statusDescription;
    
        public Payload(){
    
        }
    
    //getters and setters
```

Comment: Are you having three tables one for payload, one for Authstatus and another for results or else its just the same

Comment: Hi @venkat just the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need intermediary objects, `Payload` needs to be a bit deeper to match exactly the format of your JSON object

```
public class Payload {
    AuthStatus authStatus;
    Results results;
    // Add boilerplate code here
}

public class AuthStatus {
    Integer authStatusCode;
    String authStatusDescription;
    // Add boilerplate code here
}

public class Results {
    Integer beepTransactionID;
    String payerTransactionID;
    String statusCode;
    String statusDescription;
    // Add boilerplate code here
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yassin and where do I set the getters and setters for the above and how do I call save?

Comment: Raymond, add the getters and setters yourself no problem with that. The saving mechanism remains the same.

Comment: `public class AuthStatus` and  `public class Results` are complaining that I dnt make them public, if they are public they are throwing an error

Comment: Create them in their own file

Comment: Which class will have the entity annotation and table name? And which one will house the primary id?

Comment: when  i added boiler plate code for `public class Payload {
    AuthStatus authStatus;
    Results results;}`, i end up with an error '`Basic' attribute type should not be 'Persistence Entity' 1

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
```

to store payload into JsonNode format as it is

Comment: hi @dhiraj, I want to extract the specific values from the json string and insert to columns ands rows, not the entire json